# Yii2 Datatable reload using pjax

Tags: php, datatables, yii2, pjax

I have this issue. I'm using yii2. And I'm using datatable to display my content. everything is fine. but when I reload table using Pjax. some div will missing. here is the screenshot:

[image]

this is before submission of pjax.

[image]

this one after submission.

anyone know how to reload also the div when reloading via pjax?
thank you.

Here is my code in _form when submit:

```
$script = <<< JS

$('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e)
{
    var \$form = $(this);
    $.post(
    \$form.attr('action'),
    \$form.serialize(),
    )
    .done(function(result){
       if (result == 1)
       {
        $(\$form).trigger('reset');
        $.pjax.reload({
            container: '#w0',
            timeout: false
        });
    } else {
        $('#message').html(result);
    }
}).fail(function()
{
    console.log('server error');
});
    return false;
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

Comment: how are you reloading as it is unclear from your question and please add the relative code how you are reloading and populating the datatables.

Comment: from my research. it says i have to re initialize data table from jquery submission. but unlucky i don't have any idea how to re-initialize scripts of datatabe when submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `Pjax` for the search filter with the `DataTable` and reloading the `Pjax` removes the initialization of the DataTable plugin from the main container.

You should use the [Events](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) provided by the Pjax plugin and for your current situation, you can use

> `pjax:complete` : always fires after ajax, regardless of the
>   result.

So you can bind the event to reload the `DataTable` script on the container like below.

```
$js=<<< JS
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
JS;
$this->registerScript($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank You so much :)